# How to do iferror vlookup in r

Tags: r

I have created a formula in excel with iferror and vlookup(mentioned below).Can you please let me know how can I replicate the same in R

This lookup goes to main_df which matches with various column named E&F

So the condition is vlookup on column E with sheet1 if error then vlookup on F with sheet2 and if error then again vlookup upon E with sheet3.So basically every time I get a NA it should pick up only those values and do the next vlookup.

```
IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E2,'sheet1'!$K:$L,2,0),VLOOKUP($F2,'sheet2'!$A:$B,2,0)),VLOOKUP($E2,'sheet3'!$N:$O,2,0))
```

**Edit:**

```
   main_df
    Countries   City
    USA         Texas
    India       Mumbai
    China       Hunan
    Veitnam     Hue
```

Other DF

```
df_sheet1                            df_sheet2
    Countries Population          City      Population
    USA       1000000             Hunan     239857688
    India     118947759           Hue       667588
```

Desired output final_df

```
main_df
Countries   City      Population
USA         Texas     1000000
India       Mumbai    118947759
China       Hunan     239857688
Veitnam     Hue       667588
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: Has you tried it yourself already?

Comment: Excel formula doesn't makes sense.

Comment: I have quoted the excel formula to make it clear..Have already explained what I am excatly looking for.The output I am looking for is all the NA should have matched values as per as the look up done.
So letz say have df with country names and the rest 3 sheet1,sheet2,sheet3 have population different sheet has different country name and population number.So the desired output would be vlook up and get all the countries population in main df.Hope that explains

Comment: Provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 are 3 different dataframes?

Comment: Yes they are different df.I already gave the example...

Comment: So basically 
`df <- c('USA','UK',India','China','Denmark','Canada','Turkey'......) 
df_sheet1                       df_sheet2                         df_sheet3
Countries  Population     Countries    Population  Countries   Population
USA          1000000         India          118947759   Turkey       567748
UK             9857688        China         239857688   Canada      667588`
Desired out put
`final_df 
countries     population
USA          1000000         
India          18947759
UK              9857688     
China       239857688
Turkey      567748
canada    667588`

Comment: sorry for not having proper format

Comment: You can edit your post.

Comment: Wouldn't `rbind` solve your problem here ? Just get your all data together and then merge it .

Comment: not possible since I need to do next vlook up when only it get NA with first vlook up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging more than 2 dataframes in R by rownames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666643/merging-more-than-2-dataframes-in-r-by-rownames)

Answer (score 1):

i assume you have two dfs as:

```
> data1
  Countries Population
1       USA    1000000
2     India  118947759

> data2
  Countries Population
1    Turkey     567748
2        UK    9857688
3     China  239857688
4    Canada     667588

> tomerge
  Countries
1       USA
2        UK
3     India
4     China
5   Denmark
6    Canada
7    Turkey
```

Run this function i found on a question on SO

```
MyMerge <- function(x, y){
              df <- merge(x, y, by= "Countries", all.x= TRUE, all.y= TRUE)
              return(df)
            }
```

Then using Reduce

```
final <- Reduce(MyMerge,list(data1,data2,tomerge))


> final
  Countries Population.x Population.y
1     India    118947759           NA
2       USA      1000000           NA
3    Canada           NA       667588
4     China           NA    239857688
5    Turkey           NA       567748
6        UK           NA      9857688
7   Denmark           NA           NA
```

Comment: The concern is that that the merge is from different df and not one...and hence the mention of df_sheet1,df_sheet2 and df_sheet3 and the main df has only counties

Comment: some what solves it but again the concern is need to do lookup for multiple column from the main df(tomerge-df) but the function gives option to merge from only one column in the df 'countries' and assume I have 'region' also in the main df to map.