# Join or merge multiple datasets in r by ID with differing numbers of rows and removing non-matching rows by creating a function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, join, merge

I have multiple (more than 2) datasets that I want to link together to create "all data". I want to match the participant ID column (that is in every single dataset) so that there is one row per participant. Previously, I have used merge to link two sets, then continued this, but I have 20+ sets of data I need to merge and this will be too complicated.

I keep getting debugging stuff pop up, or errors related to the fact that there are differing numbers of rows. I want to remove any rows that does not match.

I have tried to create a function like this, based on code from here and other pieces of functions I can find: [Merging more than 2 dataframes in R by rownames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666643/merging-more-than-2-dataframes-in-r-by-rownames)

> MyMerge <- function(x, y){   df <- merge(x, y, by = "P_ID", all.x = F,
> all.y = F, sort = T, incomparables = NULL)   intersect(names(x),
> names(y))   return(df) }

I have also tried it with `by = "col.names"` and
`filter(!x$P_ID %in% !y$P_ID)` and changing true and false

Then if I run the code as

```
All.data <- Reduce(MyMerge, list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, by = "P_ID"))
```

or

```
All.data <- MyMerge(c(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, by = "P_ID"))
```

I get

> error during wrapup:'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

but every df has "P_ID" in it, so I assume this is related to the fact that not all participants are in all datasets, as I get an error saying

> error during wrapup: arguments imply differing numbers of rows

when I run the function as:

```
MyMerge <- function(x, y){
  df <- merge(x, y, by = "col.names", all.x = F, all.y = F, sort = TRUE, incomparables = TRUE)
  colnames(df) <- df$Col.names
  df$Col.names <- NULL
  return(df)
}
```

There is probably a really simple solution out there, but I am relatively new to R, and not that skilled in creating functions etc.

All datasets have different columns, they only share the ID column, so can't do `rbind`, maybe `cbind`, but because of uneven number of rows I wanted to merge and remove rows that don't match on ID.